# in Lua, how can I use a table as varargs (...)?

Tags: lua

strjoin accepts one string and then a variable number of arguments. I'm looking for a way to take a table with a variable number of arguments and use each item in the table as another argument.

```
local myTable = {
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
}
-- This is what I want except that I don't want to hard code
-- a specific number of parameters

local myString = strjoin(' ', myTable[1], myTable[2], myTable[3])
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the [unpack](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-unpack) function:

```
local myString = strjoin(' ', unpack(myTable))
```

Newer versions of Lua place the [unpack function in the table module](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.unpack):

```
local myString = strjoin(' ', table.unpack(myTable))
```

This doesn't answer your question directly, but as [lhf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476071/1491) pointed out, the following is much more efficient:

```
local myString = table.concat(myTable, ' ')
```

Comment: I had to use `table.unpack` instead of just `unpack`. Might be a version difference.

Comment: I too had to use `table.unpack`. This may be do to the ["new module system" introduced in Lua 5.1](https://www.lua.org/versions.html).

Comment: Yes, the unpack function was moved to the table module in Lua 5.2. This answer is 8 years old. So, I couldn't predict the future. ;) I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use `table.concat` instead of `strjoin`.

Comment: While technically you are correct, your answer was not chosen because I am looking for a solution I can also apply to some other similar functions.

Comment: @AsaAyers, then you'd better find/request from devs functions that would work with tables because your program will fails once you try this with table of 200+ values, as it will overflow Lua local function stack.