# Returning the inside of a table from a function

Tags: lua

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [in Lua, how can I use a table as varargs (…)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473770/in-lua-how-can-i-use-a-table-as-varargs)

I'd like to do something similar to the following and I was wondering if it is at all possible with lua?

```lua
fun = function()
    some_table = {1,2,3}
    -- some dark magic here
    return 1,2,3
end

a, b, c = fun()
```

How to convert `{1,2,3}` to `1,2,3` for just returning from the function?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [unpack()](http://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html) (renamed to `table.unpack` in Lua 5.2):

```
fun = function()
  some_table = {1,2,3}
  return (table.unpack or unpack)(some_table)
end
print(fun())
```

will print `1 2 3`.